# Append CSS style from a bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to append a style during @PostConstruct of a component, for example to a CommandButton. Change the style class is here no way because I need dynamic values.

I tried the following which resets the style of the Button

```
UIViewRoot root = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
CommandButton button = (CommandButton)root.findComponent("form:btn1");
button.setStyle("background-color: red;");
```

Comment: Can you please share more information about the goal you want to achieve? There might be much easier solutions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign style to `commandButton` dynamically by using expression language:

```
<p:commandButton ... style="#{bean.buttonStyle}" ... />
```